# Voltage Sequence in Three Phase System from wattmeter reading

Tags: power, three-phase

How does one identify the phase sequence of voltages in a balanced 3 phase system solely from the readings of two wattmeters connected properly to measure total power? I am referring to the two wattmeter method and the relevance of sequence in it.

Comment: Whether the watts read +ve or -ve depends on the phasing of the current sense with respect to the voltage sense. This is the 'proper' connection you refer to. It's independent of the order of the phases, either order will result in a 'proper' connection.

Comment: Can't the sequence be inferred from the readings though?

Comment: I've just said no. Which part of no are you having trouble with? A 'three phase sequence meter' works differently to a wattmeter.

Answer (score 1):

Lets use a Pumped-storage hydroelectricity for an example.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity#Direct_pumping

The turbines of this storage could operate as both turbine-generators and in reverse as electric motor driven pumps. If such a wattmeter is inserted between the grid and the generator/motor of the pump storage, it will show how much power flows and the direction of flow when electric energy is stored or released. But the sequence of the 3 phase system never changes, the generators of the grid always rotate in the same direction. The wattmeters may show any value between plus and minus 100 % but the phase sequence never changes. There is no relation between the reading of the wattmeters and the phase sequence.